# encode der with openssl

Tags: digital-signature

When you issue `openssl dgst -sign key <file` it follows the `PKCS#1` standard to generate a digital signature.

1. hash `file` with some hash digest function
2. encode the hashed value in `DER` format, specifying the hash function used, and the hash function used.
3. sign the actual binary `DER` data with `RSA PKCS#1`, which pads it if needed.

I want to do these actions step by step with the `openssl` command line.

I can use `openssl dgst <file` to generate a hash.

I can use `openssl rsautl -sign -inkey key -in file` to generate RSA signature for `file`, and pad it correctly.

But I don't know how to take the hash, and encode it with the appropriate DER format. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASN.1 structure we are talking about here is:

```
DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    digestAlgorithm  AlgorithmIdentifier,
    digest           OCTET STRING
}

AlgorithmIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
    algorithm        OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
    parameters       ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL
}
```

When encoded in DER, the actual hash value (the raw bytes) will be located at the very end of the encoded structure. So the DER encoding of the structure, for a given hash function, is equivalent to concatenating a fixed string of bytes with the hash value. The string of bytes for various hash functions are given *in extenso* in [PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) (section 9.2, page 38 of version 2.1 of the standard).

So, on a Unix-like system, to get from hash value contained in file `hash-value.bin` to the DER-encoded structure specifying SHA-256, you would do this:

```
(printf '\x30\x31\x30\x0d\x06\x09\x60\x86\x48\x01\x65\x03\x04\x02\x01\x05\x00\x04\x20' ; cat hash-value.bin) > encoded-hash.der
```

---

The Devil hides in the details, and ASN.1 is so much full of details that it should rightfully be burnt at the stake. In this case, notice how the `parameters` field is marked `OPTIONAL`. In a much older version of another standard, a typographic error resulted in the omission of that keyword; hence, some implementers found it that they *had* to include some parameters, even so the OID was enough to designate the hash function. Hence, they added an ASN.1 `NULL` value as parameters (it shows as the `0x05 0x00` bytes in the encoded headers). However, some later implementers found it fit to "correct" the issue and omit the unneeded parameters altogether, as is permitted by the `OPTIONAL` keyword. The bottom-line is the following: for a given hash function, there are *two* versions of the "fixed header string" to be concatenated with the hash value. For instance, for SHA-256, PKCS#1 says that the header is:

```
30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20
```

but one may also encounter this alternate header:

```
30 2f 30 0b 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 04 20
```

which some implementation use. According to PKCS#1, you *shall* use the first one when producing signature, but you also *shall* accept both when verifying signatures.

Comment: So, no way for openssl to generate the header for me, or at least do `openssl derseq file1 file2`. Bummer, but thanks.